PrismaClientValidationError: next13
It gives the following error to connect with Stripe
I used MongoDB and Stripe in this project
Thank you for the guidance
fetch("/api/create-payment-intent"
checkoutClient.tsx:86
POST localhost:3000/api/create-payment-intent 500 (Internal Server Error)
eval    @   checkoutClient.tsx:86
Show 138 more frames
"use client";
const CheckoutClient = () => {
  const { cartProducts, paymentIntent, handleSetPaymentIntent } = useCart();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState("");

  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    //create a paymentintant s soon as the page loads
    if (cartProducts) {
      setLoading(true);
      setError(false);
      fetch("/api/create-payment-intent", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          items: cartProducts,
          payment_intent_id: paymentIntent,
        }),
      })
        .then((res) => {
          setLoading(false);
          if (res.status === 401) {
            return router.push("/login");
          }
          return res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          setClientSecret(data.paymentIntent.client_secret);
          handleSetPaymentIntent(data.paymentIntent.id);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setError(true);
          console.log("Error:>>>>", error);
          toast.error("something went wrong");
        });
    }
  }, [cartProducts, paymentIntent]);

  return <>checkout</>;
};


router:


const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY as string, {
  apiVersion: "2024-04-10",
});

const calculatorOrderAmount = (items: CartProductType[]) => {
  const totalPrice = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const itemTotal = item.price * item.quantity;
    return acc + itemTotal;
  }, 0);

  const price: any = Math.floor(totalPrice);
  return price;
};

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();

  if (!currentUser) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: "Unauthorized" }, { status: 401 });
  }
  const body = await request.json();
  const { items, payment_intent_id } = body;
  const total = calculatorOrderAmount(items) * 100;
  const orderData = {
    user: {
      connect: { id: currentUser.id },
    },
    amount: total,
    currency: "usd",
    status: "pending",
    deliveryStatus: "pending",
    paymentIntentId: payment_intent_id,
    products: items,
  };

  if (payment_intent_id) {
    const current_intent = await stripe.paymentIntents.retrieve(
      payment_intent_id
    );

    if (current_intent) {
      const updated_intent = await stripe.paymentIntents.update(
        payment_intent_id,
        { amount: total }
      );

      // update the order

      const [existing_order, update_order] = await Promise.all([
        prisma.order.findFirst({
          where: { paymentIntentId: payment_intent_id },
        }),
        prisma.order.update({
          where: {
            paymentIntentId: payment_intent_id,
          },
          data: {
            amount: total,
            products: items,
          },
        }),
      ]);

      if (!existing_order) {
        return NextResponse.json(
          { error: "Invalid Payment Intent" },
          { status: 400 }
        );
      }
      return NextResponse.json({ paymentIntent: updated_intent });
    }
  } else {
    //create the intent
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: total,
      currency: "usd",
      automatic_payment_methods: { enabled: true },
    });
    // create the order

    orderData.paymentIntentId = paymentIntent.id;
    await prisma.order.create({
      data: orderData,
    });

    return NextResponse.json({ paymentIntent });
  }
}



It looks like a 500 error on your server. Put debug log on server and inspect which exact line is throwing the error.
